# Android styles with CSS-like selection?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gui

As an example, the view of my application consists of a LinearLayout which holds some TextViews and a Button. The TextViews all have the same style, e.g. a blue textColor, just like this:

```
<LinearLayout>
    <TextView style="@style/my_style" />
    <TextView style="@style/my_style" />
    <TextView style="@style/my_style" />
    <TextView style="@style/my_style" />
    <Button />
</LinearLayout>
```

In my eyes this is very redundant and having worked with web technologies before, I ask myself if there is any way to use styles in android the same way as CSS works with HTML.

What I want is a layout description like this:

```
<LinearLayout style="@style/my_style">
    <TextView />
    <TextView />
    <TextView />
    <TextView />
    <Button />
</LinearLayout>
```

The style in this case could be the following:

```
<style name="my_style">
    <TextView>
        <item name="android:textColor">#ff0000ff</item>
    </TextView>
</style>
```

Can this be done in Android? It seems styles and themes are not powerful enough to achieve this.

This is just a simple example and I imagine more complex and nested styles with inclusion and exclusion rules for elements to style.

Thank you for your suggestions!

Comment: Nope thats not possible I think. If the attribute style is in LinearLayout then it will be applied to the LinearLayout itself

Comment: Yeah, I already tried something like this and it did not work. What a bummer. This makes styling an application extremely difficult and tediuos.

Comment: Yeah but you can achieve it programatically

Comment: You can get the children of a layout and then apply specific style to all of them!!!

Comment: Yes, but "doing it programatically" does feel very very wrong. Android defines layouts, styles and themes via xml; there should not be any reason for writing code to achieve simple styling for a larger number of elements.

Comment: Yes I agree with you. But sometimes we need to do some tricks if we have no other choice right? Else we can customize the views with specific styles, but thats also makes some trouble.